# Mysql Query Improve Performance

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

i have the following Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(sid),fDate,COUNT(DISTINCT(cid)) 
    FROM forwarding  
    WHERE fDate BETWEEN "2011-06-01" AND "2011-06-30" 
    GROUP BY fDate
```

Explain gives me the following output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  forwarding  index   fDate,fDate_2   fDate_2 3       1481127 Using where
```

You can see that there is a lot of data.
The total working Time is 12seconds.
How can i improve the performance? I don't know what i can do more as setting the index.

There are my indices for this table:

```
fDate (fDate, f_shop)
fDate2(dDate),
f_shop(f_shop)
```

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE:

Now i added a column in my where clause and the query is much slower then before.

```
SELECT COUNT(sid),fDate,COUNT(DISTINCT(cid)) FROM forwarding 
WHERE fDate BETWEEN "2011-06-01" AND "2011-06-30"  AND f_shop=10077 GROUP BY fDate
```

I have an index on forwardDate and f_shop but the performance is to slow. What is the perfect solution?
Thank you

Comment: And if `sid` cannot be `NULL`, use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(sid)`

Comment: And a question: is `fDate` of `DATE` type or of `DATETIME` ?

Comment: fDate is a Date Type. I will try the other tips. thanks

Comment: Notice that is (for example) the query with `WHERE fDate BETWEEN '2011-06-01' AND '2011-06-02'` uses some index but yours does not, you can't do much. MySQL decides (usually correctly!) that it's better **not** to use any index but full scan (a big) part of the table.

Comment: i don't understand your last comment because the new index works fine. Thank you very much. Could you describe why the index must set to fDate and cid? Now it's just < 3seconds. :)  Bute the tip with Count(*) doesn't help.

Comment: How many rows does the table have? How many of those are `fDate BETWEEN "2011-06-01" AND "2011-06-30"`? And how many rows does the query return?

Comment: You can also run `ANALYZE forwarding` to update table's statistics.

Comment: The `(fDate, cid)` index works because of the `DISTINCT cid` you have. You query has to find for every `fDate` how many distinct `cid` exist. If it can do it using an index (without reading any data from the table), it's faster than scanning the full table.

Comment: @Darhazer: If you want to notify ypercube, you should stick an @ in front of their name.

Comment: @ypercube pls post an answer, 'cause you've actually answered the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) answered all my questions concerning MySQL indexes so far. It might be worth a read.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to ypercube's offered answer,  your query where you are looking for a specific shop...  I would have an index on

(f_shop, fdate, cid) to ensure all 3 parts of the index are utilized with the smallest WHERE clause qualifier in front.. in your last sample, you've included interest in a specific shop...

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(sid),
      fDate,
      COUNT(DISTINCT(cid)) 
   FROM 
      forwarding 
   WHERE 
          f_shop=10077 
      AND fDate BETWEEN "2011-06-01" AND "2011-06-30"
   GROUP BY 
      fDate
```

Comment: yeah, thank you very much. Is the order important for the index? How could i know that fDate and f_shop aren't enough?

Comment: @user954740, yes, order is important and should be in order of the most granular piece you are trying to find based on common querying.  In this case, I would assume F_SHOP because you could have 100+ F_SHOP entries.  So, scanning by date range first, you would still skip over all the other "shops".  By having that in the first position, you are STARTING with the one shop, then within that, only the date range you are concerned with.